Linux LVM disk partitioning scheme for a server?
I would like to know the disk layout / partitioning setup on a linux server.
From what I know, you need to have a physical EFI partition if it's a UEFI system (arch wiki).
Also you need (recommended) a physical /boot partition for the kernel images etc.
And the rest of the disk space is allocated as a lvm physical volume for swaplv rootlv usr var whatever you fancy etc in the rootvg.
So , the disk layout in my mind looks somewhat like this :
--> EFI partition (/dev/sda1)
--> /boot partition (/dev/sda2)
--> /dev/sda3 containing the LVM structures.
Is this how usually a disk is setup on a linux server ?
Which brings me to my core question - If the above is true, then does it mean, while mirroring the logical volumes (rootlv say), then you have to create the exact 3 matching partitions on another disk ? (/dev/sdb say).
I ask this because I know that the disks should be of equal size , otherwise the data on one disk might outgrow another and the data could be out of sync with possible errors.
If the above setup is not valid, then what is the proper lvm setup for a server ?

The structure is broadly correct. For a server I'd be looking at storage resilience through RAID (and quite possibly dual PSUs, dual NICs, UPS, etc. but that's hardware and pretty much off-topic here). And backups. Always backups.
Other things to consider:

My "typical" server build has been RAID1/5/6 then LUKS and then LVM. (I try to avoid RAID5 as there's lots of hard work overhead for not a lot of resilience. I prefer RAID6 to RAID10, but others will argue the opposite.)
As an alternative to RAID+LVM, take a close look at ZFS or BTRFS. But do make sure whatever you choose can handle at least one concurrent disk failure.
Backups. Don't forget backups. And recovery: how long can you afford for this server to be offline and how much data can you afford to have lost since the last backup?

Now, in response to the "core question",

does it mean, while mirroring the logical volumes (rootlv say), then you have to create the exact 3 matching partitions on another disk?

Yes and no. When you create a mirror from two or more partitions it will be sized to fit the smallest of the set. As a corollary you cannot add a partition or disk to an array that is smaller than the smallest partition hosting the array.

I would create the EFI partition on every disk, and mirror it (manually if necessary). There's little harm having a backup ready to run.
I would mirror /boot either using RAID1 across n disks such that the RAID metadata is at the end of the partition or manually each time it's updated.
Your remaining partition size should match across all the disks you're going to mirror (subject to the caveat stated above).


Thanks. I tried this setup in virtualbox with 2 vdi disks from a ssd partition using the host i/o cache. The whole disk io was so slow. Was simple in case of AIX , just add the disk and mirrorvg rootvg did it.

Does this setup mean , you have to install the bootloader on both disks as well ?

Of course it's going to be slow if you implement this as a VM. Multiple reads/writes for a RAID emulated on a single disk will always be slow. In such a case you wouldn't use any RAID but leave that to the host to provide resilient storage. I probably wouldn't bother with LUKS either, for the same reason
